# Are there more biters in multiplayer?

Tags: factorio

In Factorio do more biters spawn in multiplayer versus singleplayer?

I've been running a server and it seems like there are a ton more bugs to the point where it is dangerous to play on the server alone. Did we just get spawned into a rough neighborhood or do MP servers generally have more biters?

The settings for the server are for the "normal" amount of biters:

> {
> "coal": {"frequency": "normal", "size": "normal", "richness": "normal"},
> "copper-ore": {"frequency": "normal", "size": "normal", "richness": "normal"},
> "crude-oil": {"frequency": "normal", "size": "normal", "richness": "normal"},
> **"enemy-base": {"frequency": "normal", "size": "normal", "richness": "normal"},**
> "iron-ore": {"frequency": "normal", "size": "normal", "richness": "normal"},
> "stone": {"frequency": "normal", "size": "normal", "richness": "normal"},
> "uranium-ore": {"frequency": "normal", "size": "normal", "richness": "normal"}   },

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no difference between singleplayer and multiplayer enemy spawning while using equal settings.

More Biters will appear over time while the server is running, even if 0 players are online. That's configurable (there is a setting to auto-pause the game while no-one is playing).

Comment: This is a good call out, but I do have 
  "_comment_auto_pause": "Whether should the server be paused when no players are present.",
  "auto_pause": true,
 setup

Answer (score 4):

How many Biters spawn is determined by the evolution factor, as is stated in the wiki:

> Besides choosing what kind of biter will be spawned, the evolution factor also influences the spawning interval. This interval (spawning_cooldown in the enemy-spawner definition) is interpolated between 360 (0 evolution) and 150 (1 evolution) game ticks (= 6 to 2.5 seconds)

There are 3 things that can increase evolution:

- The passage of time very slightly increases the evolution factor.
- The global pollution production increases the evolution factor.
- Destroying nests significantly increases the evolution factor.

If you want to find what evolution factor you have you can run the following command in the console:

> /evolution

Keep in mind the evolution factor is in a range of 0 (lowest) to 1 (highest).

You can find more information on evolution here: https://wiki.factorio.com/Enemies#Evolution

Answer (score 2):

Biter and spitter nests consume pollution, and when they consumed enough, they spawn a new enemy. So the number of biter spawns is a function of how much pollution the player(s) generate.

More players are usually more productive and thus create more pollution which in turn results in more biters getting spawned.